# Terraform: adding loadbalancer ip to ec2 instance security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Im facing a problem where i can access my two ec2 instances from the public subnet just fine individually by their IPs, but not from behind the loadbalancer, where i get a 504.  Both the ec2 instances and the loadbalancer use the same security group - which allow a single ip on for ingress

```
resource "aws_security_group" "security_group" {
  name   = "${var.name}_security_group"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
    
  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = var.sg_allowable_ips #for now this is a list of a single IP
  }
    
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}


resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  for_each               = var.instance_specs
  instance_type          = each.value.instance_type
  ami                    = each.value.ami
  key_name               = aws_key_pair.auth_key.id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.security_group.id]
  subnet_id = var.subnets[each.value.subnet_key].id
}
```

The issue is that security group.  If in AWS console i add the loadbalancer ip to the security group's allowable ingress ips, im then able to get to my instances from the loadbalancer just fine.
So my question is: using terraform, how can i allow the loadbalancer to access these instances if i dont yet know it's ip and it is the last thing created in my terraform script?

***UPDATE:***: the order of how im creating the resources.  notice the circular dependency between ec2 and alb modules...the ec2 module create and exposes the security group, which alb also uses.  given that my security group has a hardcoded ingress ip and is created before the alb, i have no opportunity to dynamically add the alb to the security group ingress:

```
module "vpc" {
  source          = "./modules/vpc"
  name_prefix     = var.name_prefix
  tags            = var.tags
  vpc_cidr        = var.vpc_cidr
  public_subnets  = var.public_subnets
  private_subnets = var.private_subnets
}
    
module "ec2" {
  source           = "./modules/ec2"
  name_prefix      = var.name_prefix
  tags             = var.tags
  dev_host_os      = var.dev_host_os
  vpc_id           = module.vpc.vpc_id
  auth_key_file    = var.auth_key_file
  subnets          = module.vpc.public_subnets
  instance_specs   = local.instance_specs
  sg_allowable_ips = var.sg_allowable_ips
}
    
module "alb" {
  source             = "./modules/alb"
  name_prefix        = var.name_prefix
  tags               = var.tags
  security_group_ids = module.ec2.security_group_ids
  subnet_ids         = values(module.vpc.public_subnets)[*].id
  vpc_id             = module.vpc.vpc_id
  instances          = module.ec2.instances
  #alb_certificate_arn =
}
```

Comment: You would probably allow the entire ALB security group inbound, i.e., ingress: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule#source_security_group_id.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is use the reference to the ALB security group instead of using the IP address range, since it can change. So that would mean changing the `ingress` part of the code to look something like:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "security_group" {
  name   = "${var.name}_security_group"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
    
  ingress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
    security_groups = [ aws_security_group.alb.id ] # or however many SGs there are
  }
    
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Note that it also might be better to use a separate [security group rule resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule) for defining ingress and egress rules.

Comment: how does one get a reference to the alb security group in this case (getting an error telling me 'alb' has not been declared in the module)?
Im not sure if this will solve the issue though - given that with this is effectively using the same security group for both (same as im doing now) - and the issue is allowing the ip of the load balancer to be able to access the instances...remember if had the alb ip manually to the security group using aws console - it works.  question is how to automate that?

Comment: You cannot do that because the IP addresses of the ALB nodes can (and probably do) change over time. Hardcoding those values is a bad practice. Which SG is assigned to the ALB? Where is the ALB defined. There are a lot of details missing, so I just gave an example with the generic name for the ALB security group.

Comment: Marko, i've updated the post to show the high level order of creation of resources.   i dont want to hard code the alb's ip for the security group - i want to dynamically reference it (or its dynamic ip) at creation time to add to the security group's ingress at creation time - but its a bit of a chicken and egg situation it seems

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-update-security-groups.html) for the information on how to configure the ALB SG.

Comment: thx..i read that.  the problem is  how to do it in terraform.  conceptually this is a simple architecture that can be done easily with aws console:  protect/deny access to your instance, and instead all access should come through the alb.  pretty simple to setup in aws console.   not so simple cause of this chicken and egg problem with terraform that i cant figure out.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is actually. You need two security groups, one for the ALB one for the EC2 instance. In the SG for the EC2 instance you would allow the ALB SG.

Answer (score 0):

the solution here was to create a security group for the load balancer which restricts the ip and port however i desire.  Then create a separate security group for my instances which accept only port 80 from the alb using an aws_security_group_rule.  in this way the relationship is setup among security groups, not actual resource ids or ips - resolving the chicken and egg issues with resource's dynamic ips.

@marko-e: i think some of this you were alluding to, it just wasnt clicking together. i thank you for iterating over this solution w/ me

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ec2_security_group" {
  name   = "${var.name}_security_group"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_lb_only" {
  type                     = "ingress"
  from_port                = 80
  to_port                  = 80
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id = "${var.lb_security_group_id}"  #security group that handles the load balancer
  security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.ec2_security_group.id}" #ec2 instance security group
}
```